# About the use of onNewIntent to use

Tags: java, android, timer, notifications

If the startup mode of activity is singleTask, this activity there is a notification, click on the notification to start the activity. Is there any way to not let him call onNewIntent method ...? Or call onNewIntent method, but does not perform I wrote in the execution onNewIntent (and the same as in onCreate method) ...... other calls, such as timing conditions arrives call onNewIntent method Shiyou perform I write in onNewIntent execution method (and the same as in onCreate method) .

I notice also calls onNew, timing will call onNew (timed pass parameters), Notice not pass parameters. Cause if you do not judge the program quit unexpectedly judgment after notice normally start the activity (that is, not let him perform I wrote execution method of onNewintent) but this timing over timing functions invalidated ......

Comment: Rephrase it correctly.Hard to understand..

Answer (score 0):

Been tangled how to judge the notification events or timed events over onNewIntent.

I bundle pass then judge later found an easier way action judgment, and I just changed successfully, as long as the distinction between notification events or timed events the over use onNewIntent on line ...

Solution from someone answer my questions from the site after： 
[From the Chinese website](http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-195758-2-1.html)